# Perform AND on two rewrite conditions in rewrites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two rewrite conditions.

**Condition A**

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile.nu$ [NC]

**Condition B**

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]

**Rewrite Rule.**

RewriteRule ^foo.html$

Now I want to write some condition like this.

**If Condition A AND Condition B then redirect to the given rule**

Can some one tell me how to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo.html$ /mobil/index.html [L]
```

condition1 and condition2 will be ANDed together.

Though your `RewriteRule` is not complete in your question.

Comment: Thank you.. Actually I am doing dns change on mobil.nu to test.com. I am planning to write these rules in test.com webservers. Do I need to change any thing. After DNS change of mobil.nu to test.nu, I should redkrect all requests to test.nu/mobil/index.html

Comment: I updated anwer as per your comment. It looks fine now. I believe after DNS change `mobile.nu` will be a CNAME for `test.com`.

Comment: Do I need to include CNAME also in the rules. Can you tell me how to do that.

Comment: CNAME is what people end up creating for the old retiring dns entry to avoid loosing customer using old dns bookmarks. You can also use a 301 rule to migrate people off old domain.

Comment: Thannks. This CNAME is to be taken care while doing dns change right. I think there would not  be any change in my rule. Apologies if my question basic.

Comment: Yes rule don't need any change and yes CNAME needs to be taken care of while doing DNS change. (I am not a server admin so just know very basic).

Answer (score 1):

You just write those conditions in order before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile.nu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo.html$ [rewrite rule]
```

That imposes an `AND` relationship between the two conditions